# apk error Failure INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE

Tags: java, android, system

I tried edit tv box launcher with apk easy tool

but it didn't installed

```
 Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.droidlogic.mboxlauncher-1: Package com.droidlogic.mboxlauncher has no signatures that match those in shared user android.uid.system; ignoring!]
```

how can I signature system app?

Comment: any one can help me ?